# How to realize function map in nginx configuration file

Tags: nginx

I have problem with my nginx configuration file. How i can do something like this in nginx.conf:

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* (Googlebot|BingBot) ) {
    if ($cookie_currency = "") {
        rewrite ^/(?!currency) /currency redirect;   
    }
}
```

i try to find something info at google, try to write for ChatGPT, but i don't understand how i can write this `map` function. With this code i have an error that i can't use if in the if statement. Also i try to write some realization map function, but i don't understand how to connect all of this statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the logic with maps:

```
map $http_user_agent $bot {
    ~*googlebot 1;
    ~*bingbot 1;
}

map $bot$cookie_currency $redirect_currency {
    "" 1;
}
```

```
if ($redirect_currency) {
    return 301 /currency;
}
```